# SQL connector using Python

Tags: python, sql

I have a SQL database which I wish to run a query on through python. I have the following code:

```
sql='select * from mf where frequency=220258.0;'
cur.execute(sql)
```

Where I use the same select command in sqlite3 directly it works, but through Python no database entries are outputted.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you get the `cur`? Do you fetch any entries from it?

Comment: Well, how are you connecting?

Comment: Which library are you using to connect to the database?

Comment: Maybe you don't understand what we're asking; could you just show us the rest of your code, or is this all of the code that you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this SQLite database.

```
$ sqlite3 so.sqlite3 .dump 
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE t (f1 integer, f2 text);
INSERT INTO "t" VALUES(1,'foo');
INSERT INTO "t" VALUES(2,'bar');
INSERT INTO "t" VALUES(3,'baz');
COMMIT;
```

Python connects and queries this database like this.

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect("so.sqlite3")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from t where f1 = 2")
print(cur.fetchone())
```

Output:

```
(2, 'bar')
```

You have to use one of [`cur.fetchone()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone), [`cur.fetchall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchall), or [`cur.fetchmany()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchmany) to get rows from the cursor. Just doing [`cur.execute()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) does not return the rows.